# Problem with auto-complete and syntax in *blade.php files with Laravel plugin in PhpStorm

Tags: laravel-5, phpstorm

I have strange problem with syntax and autocomplete in blade files. Yesterday it's worked normally, I didn't update any plugins or PhpStorm, I have newest versions.

After closing PhpStorm and launching it again couple of hours later, blade files stopped working. At the beginning HTML not worked too, but I changed some configuration in `Editor > File Types` and syntax for HTML came back (next I removed every changes and it still working for HTML code).

I had turn on Laravel Plugin and Blade Syntax in plugins. Syntax for directives don't had colors and auto-complete not working, tags `{{}}` etc. not working too. I fully removed PhpStorm, used Invalidate caches and this not helped me with that problem.

Under this post you can see how it looks like, directives should have purple color syntax, php code not working.

Could someone help me with that problem? I will be very appreciated. (I tried find some information in the google, but with no effect.)

Screen with code
[image: screen with code]

Whole IDE
[image: whole IDE]

Before broke
[image: before broke]

New photo without material design theme
[image: new photo without material design theme]

Comment: Post screenshot for the whole editor tab or even better: whole IDE window.

Comment: @LazyOne Hello, I added some screenshots to the main thread.

Comment: The 1st image with broken stuff is not good -- I do not see what file is that (how  IDE treats that file). Please show the same but with just one file opened (ideally without Material UI Theme ... but hopefully it will be OK as is).

Comment: @LazyOne I added without material design, last photo in topic.

Comment: Thanks. The file is clearly treated as **plain PHP**. Therefore 1) Please ensure that "Blade Support" plugin is enabled. Restart IDE if it has been disabled. 2) If plugin is OK, make sure that `*.blade.php` pattern is associated with Blade in `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | File Types`

Comment: @LazyOne I can't belive that, I tested it yesterday and added blade pattern to the blade in File Types, but it didn't work. Thanks for your time, you saved my time work...